# Brownian motion hitting probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be a brownian motion and $g(t)$ a function of the time $t$. $B_0=0$. Let $\Phi$ be the c.d.f. of a normal distribution. At time $t$, the probability that $B_t > g(t)$ equals $1-\Phi(g(t))$.

Now define some $T$. I would like to know the probability that $B_t > g(t)$ at least once during the time $t\in [0;T]$.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see some reason for this to have a solution for a general function $g$?

Comment: If what you are actually seeking is the result for a given g and T, it would be really easy to find using simulation.

Comment: @Did: Would you mind giving an answer in case $g(t)$ is a constant?